# How to delete extra non functional scanner?

Tags: drivers, scanner, xsane

I have an HP laser Jet Scanner.  Most scanning software I try to run does not find the scanner.  Xsane sees 2 of the same scanner but only works if I select the second.  I suspect the other scanner programs just try the default an give up.  Is there a way to delete the first non functional one?  [image: xzane]

Answer (score 1):

From the second Xsane entry we see you have installed sane-airscan. That is good. It is advised to keep it on your system.

The first entry may be removed from the list in one of two ways:

- Comment out **hpaio** in **/etc/sane.d/dll.d/hplip.**
- **apt purge libsane-hpaio.**

Comment: That worked.  It looks like Xsane can not scan multiple pages from a doc feeder.  Is there  another app that can?